# ¿Como pasar una fecha a base de datos MySQL con tres inputs (dia, mes, fecha)?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, base-de-datos

he diseñado un formulario en html y css asi que ahora estoy validando e ingresando los datos a la base de datos. No he tenido mayores problemas hasta el momento de introducir una fecha pues tiene el siguiente formato:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto me trae problemas al momento de extraer el dato del select en una variable PHP ya que deberian ser 3 variables distintas pero a la base de datos debo enviarlo como una sola. Al momento este es mi codigo:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","coto");


if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
        if(strlen($_POST['nombre']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['apellido'])){
                $nombre = trim($_POST['nombre']);
                $apellido = trim($_POST['apellido']);
                $pais = trim($_POST['pais']);
                $dia = trim($_POST['fecha1']);
                $mes = trim($_POST['fecha2']);
                $año = trim($_POST['fecha3']);
                $sexo = trim($_POST['sexo']);
                $documento = trim($_POST['documento']);
                $pais = trim($_POST['pais']);
                $estadoCivil = trim($_POST['estadoCivil']);
                $nDocumento = trim($_POST['ndocumento']);
                $email = trim($_POST['email']);
                $conocimiento = trim($_POST['conocimiento']);
                $prefijo = trim($_POST['prefijo']);
                $telefono = trim($_POST['telefono']);
                $usuario = trim($_POST['usuario']);
                $password = trim($_POST['password']);
                $pregunta = trim($_POST['pregunta']);
                $respuesta = trim($_POST['respuesta']);

                $telefono_entero = $prefijo.$telefono;

                
                $fecha_entera = `{$dia}/{$mes}/{$año}`;

               

                $consulta = "INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`Usuario`, `Contraseña`, `Nombre`, `Apellido`, `Pais`, `Sexo`, `Documento`, `N Documento`, `Estado Civil`, `Email`, `Descubrimiento`, `Telefono`, `Pregunta`, `Respuesta`) VALUES ('$usuario', '$password', '$nombre', '$apellido', '$pais', '$sexo', '$documento', '$nDocumento', '$estadoCivil', '$email', '$conocimiento', '$telefono_entero', '$pregunta', '$respuesta')";

                $resultado = mysqli_query($con,$consulta);


                if ($resultado) {
                        ?> 
                        <h3>¡Te has inscripto correctamente!</h3>
                        
                         <?php
                        
                } else {
                        ?> 
                        <h3>¡Ups ha ocurrido un error!</h3>
                         <?php
                         
                       
                }


        }
   
}

?>
```

He intentado varias estrategias, como se ve en el codigo probe con backtics y no lo logre pues no me lo acepta la base de datos, tambien probe hacer concatenaciones del tipo:

```
$fecha_entera = $dia.$mes.$año;
```

Pero tampoco funcionó. Cabe aclarar que el campo en la base de datos es VARCHAR ya que poniendolo de tipo DATE se me hacia mas dificil. Espero haber sido claro. Dejo una foto de la tabla por si es necesario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZACION:** Ya pude lograr que al menos se guarde algo en la base de datos en el campo de fecha pero no logro que se guarden mis variables. Unicamente almacena un valor si se los doy manualmente:

```
INSERT INTO ... '2021' '08' '05'
```

De ese modo si almacena la fecha, en cambio, si reemplazo los valores por

```
INSERT INTO ... '$año' '$mes' '$fecha';
```

O tambien:

```
INSERT INTO ... '$fecha_entera';
```

No funciona y nose por que, tambien intente lo que comentaron de utilizar

```
INSER INTO ... STR_TO_UPDATE('$fecha_entera', "%d%M%Y");
```

Pero me tira el error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$consulta' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\database2.php on line 39
```

En la base de datos unicamente se almacena **0000-00-00** salvo que, como aclare, de los valores manualmente, en ese caso si se almacena como **2021-08-05**

Comment: *Cabe aclarar que el campo en la base de datos es VARCHAR ya que poniendolo de tipo DATE se me hacia mas dificil.* Te advierto que cometes un grave error al pensar eso. Debiste declarar la columna del tipo `DATE` y luego armar la fecha así simplemente: `$fecha_entera = $año.$mes.$dia;`, eso es debido a que las columnas `DATE` y `DATETIME` en la base de datos deben guardarse con formato `AñoMesDía`. Si tú la declaras VARCHAR te expones a errores, y luego deberás pasarte la vida convirtiendo a DATE para hacer cálculos, comparaciones, etc. Intenta así y si tienes errores nos dices.

Comment: Otra cosa: no veo que en el INSERT incluyas el valor de `$fecha_entera` para que sea insertado, de modo que es imposible que se cree ese valor en la nueva fila.

Comment: No se exactamente que tienes pensado hacer con ese dato, pero depende del uso podrías convertir los 3 campos en un datetime y guardarlo así. Con esto consigues que al hacer selección de fechas y usarlo para cálculos, sea más simple y rápido, siempre debemos pensar en optimizar los recursos. Planteanos tus intereses y también te podemos ayudar con eso. Por cierto, el campo `password` espero que lo estés cifrando antes de enviarlo a php

Comment: @A.Cedano Cambie ese campo en la base de datos y use la cadena de string pero no funcionó por lo que puse en la actualizacion. En cuanto al INSERT lo habia sacado para que la web siga funcionando mientras hacia otras modificaciones, gracias.

Comment: PD: Perdón si hay otra forma de añadir actualización o algo así (si la hay agradecería que la mencionen) , aun soy nuevo y no conozco bien el uso de la web.

Comment: Observa que en los elementos `select`  (HTML) ni el mes ni el año tiene datos en `value`, por eso está tomando sólo el día. Puedes poner por ejemplo: `<option value="01">Enero</option> <option value="02">Febrero</option>` ... etc... Igualmente para el año: `<option value="2021">2021</option>` y para que tengas menos problemas a la hora de crear la fecha, pon también los días con valores de dos cifras, por ejemplo: `<option value="01">1</option> <option value="02">2</option>` ... etc ... Así debería funcionar.

Comment: Prueba con `$fecha_entera = implode('-',[$año,$mes,$dia]);`

Comment: @Sal Muchas gracias, funcionó a la perfeccion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Saludos.**

**Campo DATE**

Lo primero que debes tener presente con las fechas lo común (de las que he usado) en Base de Datos es que su formato es `Año-Mes-Dia`; sí, así como se ve separados por guión.

Sin importar el formato que le des (siempre que cada elemento cumpla con sus valores permitidos) te sugiero apoyarte en función [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp); el cual requiere dos valores, el primero es tu fecha y el segundo el formato en el cual esta; es decir si pasas `Dia-Mes-Año`, `Año-Dia-Mes`, etc... y desde luego el separador en cada elemento; por ejemplo consideremos lo armas:

```
$fecha_entera = `{$dia}/{$mes}/{$año}`;
```

para guardarlo como fecha sería convirtiéndolo:

```
[lo que uses ya sea INSERT, UPDATE, WHERE...] STR_TO_DATE('$fecha_entera', '%d/%M/%Y');
```

**Campo VARCHAR**

No es bueno usarlo así, por que desearas en algún momento buscar algo por año, por mes, de un rango de fecha, que sean de un día X, en fin muchas cosas que de todas formas tendrás que convertir a fecha para facilitar ello. En tal caso tendrías que guardar primero el Año, Mes y Dia en ese orden con un separador en común para luego poder manipularlo.

Además, (`FechaNacimiento`) si es el único dato `DATE` que actualmente tienes como `VARCHAR` su longitud no debería ser mayor a 10 datos que serían 4 para el año, dos para el mes y dos para el día más 2 separadores.

Espero te sea de utilidad.